# where is peopleresults.aspx page in sharepoint search?

Tags: search

I am define my contact list, and the made it serachable trough SSP-> serach settings. Now, I add the people search Webpart which is out of box web part. ok? but when I go to search any keyword it redirect me on **peopleresults.aspx** page. with message

"404 NOT FOUND" Or some times before it was showing me "page cannot find" error. So what is the reason? How to configure "peopleresults.aspx" with People Search box? please guide me its too urgent.

Answer (score 0):

you need to create my site and under configuration of userprofile -> setup my site enter my site host location

Please refer following location

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/bf19ece2-6846-47d1-91fe-69162417d788/people-search-not-working-peopleresultsaspx-page-does-not-exist-and-people-search-webparts-missing?forum=sharepointadminprevious

Comment: Perhaps you can include the relevant text from that link, in case the link is ever invalid.